# Is "bedsit" more commonly primarily stressed on the first or second syllable?

Tags: pronunciation, stress

*Bedsit* is one of those Britishisms that seem <s>mildly</s> extremely amusing *(in a way that's not at all intentionally offensive, insulting, derogatory, incendiary)* but not too out of the ordinary, so I just assumed it was innocuously pronounced /ˈbedsɪt/ or perhaps /ˈbedˌsɪt/, with the primary stress on the first syllable, because that's sort of how compounds are stressed in general, as opposed to mere phrases (compare *the White House* and *the white house*). Especially something like *bedsit*, whose spelling alone oozes compoundness.

But then I actually looked up the pronunciation in the [*Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bedsit), and it gave only /ˌbedˈsɪt/, with the primary stress on the second syllable. This is corroborated by the eminent Professor John C. Wells in his *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary*, whose primary pronunciation for *bedsit* also primarily stresses on the second syllable, with an inferred less common pronunciation stressed on the first syllable. Which is slightly odd, but the Brits are kind of funny with their word choices, so whatever. The commonness of this pronunciation should be immediately felt, given even an American dictionary like [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bedsit) recommends it.

But then I actually heard native British speakers use the word, and it sounded nothing like that. [Speakers on YouTube](https://youglish.com/pronounce/bedsit/english?) seem to consistently stress the first syllable more, with a noticeably weaker stress on the second. And then I looked up the word in the [*Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bedsit?q=bedsit), the [*Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bedsit), the [*Collins Cobuild Dictionary*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bedsit) and the [*MacMillan Dictionary*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bedsit), all of which without fail recommend the stressed first syllable, some of which even omit a possible secondary stress on the second. To make it worse, the actual audio sample provided by the *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* for the British pronunciation sounds very much in diametric opposition to the written transcription, also provided by the same bloody dictionary!

I honestly don't know which source to believe. On the one hand, the limited sample of native speakers and many dictionaries seem to agree on the stressed first syllable. On the other hand, there's a respected phonetician who edited a dictionary specifically about pronunciation and who maintains otherwise, even though his very own dictionary appears to contradict itself!

I'm aware this question might be voted closed for being opinion-based, but at the very least I sincerely implore any of you native speakers to just give me your personal impression and experience, because I've been losing sleep over this stupid, stupid word that I don't even use ever.

Comment: As a native British English speaker: invariably on the first syllable. Aside: I find your use of the term 'Britishisms' mildly amusing, considering that my region of UK is England, where English originated.

Comment: Re the edit about the contradiction in Longman between written and spoken, Longman gives two audio samples with different emphasis. The first, tagged 'British' is how we say it. The second is tagged 'American', isn't how we say **bedsit** (which Longman gives as British English). So, Americans mispronounce a word which they don't use.

Comment: I can't speak for Longman or Wells. Maybe there's some variant. But I can speak for myself. Speaking for myself, I've only ever heard it with 'bed' stressed, never 'sit'. I'm not putting this as an answer because the sources I'd use to back this up, you've already explained and included in your question, so in that way, you've provided the answer I would've provided, Longman and Wells notwithstanding, but then I'd be surprised if there are any sources that expressly contradict Longman and Wells here, not because none would necessarily but because contradicting would require awareness of it.

Comment: I'm American and I've never heard this word before. Intuitively, stressing the second syllable makes it seem more like a verb.

Comment: Why do you need to say that you find a word in a language other than your own mildly amusing? Your personal attitudes are of no relevance to this SE, and as a native speaker of that language I find your remarks mildly offensive. I suggest you delete them.

Comment: @David Then you contradict yourself, for you allow your own personal attitude to show. We are all tolerant here. :)

Comment: As one of those 'funny Brits', I'm surprised that Oxford Languages puts the stress on _bed_. It's a 'bed-sitting room' (a room having both functions), not a room for 'bedsitting' like 'babysitting'!

Comment: @KateBunting *Bedsit* seems to be a contraction of *bedSITting room* (of course it's funny!), so it's not so unreasonable to assume the primary stress should be on *sit* and not *bed*. But it does seem assumptions simply don't cut it, especially when words like *bedsit* have been completely *lexicalized*, rather than some quirky idiosyncratic shorthand.

Comment: *Bedsit* as a word seems to be going out of fashion, dating back to an era of boarding houses. I'm not sure to what extent it's still in the day-to-day lexicon of people, as opposed to a word encountered in 1970s literature.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw don't you know that for British people "mildly amusing" means "outrageously funny"?

Comment: @Stuart perhaps "studio flat" or "shared house" are more common now.

Comment: As an American who has never used this word, it would seem more intuitive to me to place the stress on the first subword (bed), similar to bedroom, bathroom, babysit, housesit, etc. Maybe bedsit is pecuiliar, though, since the compound word itself is a noun whilst the subword "sit" is primary a verb. In any case, someone who often uses this word in its natural setting ought to answer, e.g. real-estate agents who can properly distinguish between bedsits and bedrooms. To my non-specialist mind, a bed-sit just sounds like a smallish bedroom.

Comment: 'don't you know that for British people "mildly amusing" means "outrageously funny"' Jesus. In that case, my sincerest apologies to @David.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw Interesting, however, if I try to pronounce "bed-sitting room" I'm going to place the primary stress on BED as well. And www.m-w.com seems to agree with this (they have an entry for bed-sitting room with that pattern recorded). Again, I've never used the word, but when I read it out, this is what I would do intuitively.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think the defining feature of a bedsit is that it's a single room, not a suite of rooms like a flat/apartment would be. Also, where do you even shower or take a poop in a bedsit, though? The plumbing logistics must be a nightmare.

Comment: The Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedsit discusses bedsits and international equivalents; most of the cultural references are from early 1980s or before. It gives North American equivalents for the building but there doesn't seem to be a N American equivalent for the room.

Comment: @Brandin - It's a _bedroom_ that is also used as a _sitting-room_ (living-room). Vun-Hugh Vaw -  The occupant would have shared use of a bathroom and possibly a kitchen, or they might have simple cooking facilities in the room.